# Displaying picture that is not in resources of Qt

Tags: c++, image, qt

I am currently writing an application in Qt, which is basically a warehouse. An application reads CSV, enables user to process it and enables to show picture of each good. I tried displaying picture using QLabel and Pixmap, however nothing happens even though the file is in the same folder and the name provided is exactly as it should be. Is it the resources issue or my code fails somehow? Is there any possibility to display the image without adding it to resources in order to avoid adding many photos manually?

```
void ImageViewer::viewImage(QString imgName)
{
    QString pathWithName = imgName;
    pathWithName.append(".jpg");

    ui->label->setPixmap( QPixmap(pathWithName) );
    ui->label->show();
    update();
}
```

Sorry for any mistakes in post creation or code displaying here- it's my first post.

Edit:
I am adding code from MainWindow (called CsvReader in my project) to how I'm invoking the method viewImage:

```
void CsvReader::on_imgView_clicked()
{
    ImageViewer* img = new ImageViewer(this);
    img->setModal(true);
    img->exec();
QModelIndex List selInd ui->tableView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
QString id = model->item(selInd.first().row(), 0)->text();

img->viewImage(id);
}
```

Edit 2: 
Solved. Had to change path using QDir:

```
QDir* directory = new QDir("/home/kokos/Magazyn/photos");
QFileInfo checkFile(*directory, pathWithName);
```

Thanks in advance,
Kokos

Comment: What does pathWithName actually contain? If it's a filename or relative path, it will be interpreted relative to the current working directory. (which is not necessarily the location of the .exe)

Comment: It is only the name of the file+.jpg . How to check from what path is file read?

Comment: Added some code concerning how the method is invoked in mainwindow

Comment: Don't create the QDir on the heap, create on the stack instead. Right now you're leaking the object (if you don't delete it later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm your file's location and existence first. Add this;

```
    QFileInfo checkFile(pathWithName);

    if (checkFile.exists() && checkFile.isFile()) {
        // your code
    }
```

Comment: I added also else:
    else
    {
        std::cout << "file does not exist" <<std::endl;
    }

And it is not printed to the console when I run it (when I remove the file from the path it is printed).

Comment: Added some code concerning how the method is invoked in mainwindow